# To zoom radiobutton and checkboxes in mozilla

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I have used some Checkboxes and Radiobuttons in site. On Zooming size of Radio Buttons and Checkboxes is getting increased in IE and Chrome.
To increase size of Radio Buttons and Checkboxes in Mozilla Firefox I have used this CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]
{
 -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]
{
 -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

But the problem is that with this CSS Radio buttons are not reflecting  properly, semi-circle part of radio button is reflecting without border.
Is there any way to fix this. Issue is reflecting only in Mozilla. Please suggest any alternative way to zoom size in Mozilla.
I am unable to post complete HTML here.

There is also a Ticket here:

```
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=400364
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
 outline: none; 
}
```

try this...